# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError when using heroku and flask

Tags: python, heroku, flask, jinja2

I have a flask app on heroku and its throws a jinja2 exception while trying to access a global function within the template. My app.py has this line

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.jinja_env.globals.update(username_fetch_by_id=db.username_fetch_by_id)
```

The error is

```
1: File "/app/templates/stream.html", line 7, in block "content"
2: <a href="{{ url_for('stream', user_id = post[1]) }}">@{{ username_fetch_by_id(post[1]) }}</a>
3: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'username_fetch_by_id' is undefined
```

The entire source code can be found [here](https://github.com/devangj/thesocialnetwork)

Comment: how are you launching the app  ? if you are using `flask run` in a shell for example, the lines inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` are not executed. Try to move all these globals declarations above this `if` statement

Comment: @PRMoureu I'm running a gunicorn server which heroku does automatically after reading the Procfile. So you're saying I just put all those lines outside `if __name__ == '__main__':`?

Comment: yep,it's worth giving a try.